# Getting the selected listValue of <s:select> in javascript

Tags: javascript, struts2

I am using  tag of struts to display a list of items.

```
<s:select name="example" id="example" list="exampleList" listKey="exampleKey" 
listValue="exampleValue" onchange="fun()"/>
```

Now I have a javascript function:

```
function fun()
{
  var ex=document.getElementById("example");
  alert(ex.value);
}
```

In this function I need to get the listValue of the selected item but when I'm using the above code, it just alerts me the listKey that I have selected. How can I get the listValue instead of listKey in the javascript function?

Comment: For JS questions please post the rendered HTML and not the JSP.

Comment: @Quaternion I added an answer with rendered HTML and a solution that seems to work quite well.

Answer (score 2):

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#reminderTypeID').change(function() 
       {
             var ex = document.getElementById("reminderTypeID");    
        var selTex = ex[$('#reminderTypeID').val()].text;
        var selVal = ex[$('#reminderTypeID').val()].value;
        alert(ex[$('#reminderTypeID').val()].text);  
      });
   });
```

Comment: Remove onchange from your code and add jquery change event in it.

Comment: Nilesh, if you are addressing the poster, then they won't be notified if you comment on your own answer. Update the answer (if required) then comment on the question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (Worked for me):

```
function fun()
{
    var ex = document.getElementById("example");
    alert(ex.getAttribute('listValue'));
}
```

**Edit**
Added fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FranWahl/Ur6jT/2/
(Not sure why it won't work for you. In the fiddle it works.)

Comment: I added a fiddle. In the fiddle the code executes on page load as I don't have the items for the list but you can see it displays the value of the attribute alright.

Comment: ya its working fine in the fiddle but i couldnt figure out whats the mistake with my code.

Comment: As `Quaternion` mentioned in a comment on your post, if you could show the rendered HTML for the tags in question. Maybe it's a scope issue or the attribute might not get rendered.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue, and neither of the other answers was working for me. This is the solution that I found worked:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#example").change(function(){
            var options = document.getElementById("example").options; 
            var selectedIndex = document.getElementById("example").selectedIndex; 
            var selectedOptionText = options[selectedIndex].text;
            var selectedOptionValue = options[selectedIndex].value;
            console.log("Id of selected option is: " + selectedOptionValue);
            console.log("Text of selected option is: " + selectedOptionText);   
        });
    });
```

To further understand the issue, it helped to think about what HTML is created when the JSP is processed. The `<s:select>` will generate the following HTML:

```
<select id="example" name="example">
    <option value="456">TextA</option>
    ...
</select>
```

Following OP's sample code, "456" would be derived from `exampleKey` and "TextA" from `exampleValue`. There would be such HTML `<option>` for each item in `exampleList`.

Note in my solution, I used the jQuery `.change()` function. However I also tried the solution with `onchange="fun()"`, as the OP had done, and that worked too.

When I tried replacing `document.getElementById("example")` with `$("#example")`, the solution did **not** work.

Also helpful was reading [this reference](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_select_selectedindex.asp) on `<select>` option selectedValue.